# SQL/PHP Create DB and load .CSV

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, bulkinsert

So far I have dropped all tables and created the database and that is working. But when I try and create a new table and load a .csv file, it won't work.

```
mysql_select_db($dbName, $dbConnection);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$dbTable." (ID int(6) auto_increment NOT NULL, Username varchar(20) NOT NULL, Password varchar(20) NOT NULL, UserType int(1) NOT NULL, FirstName varchar(15) NOT NULL, LastName varchar(15) NOT NULL, DOB DATETIME NOT NULL, Phone varchar(15) NOT NULL, Department varchar(15),PRIMARY KEY(ID))";
if(mysql_query($sql, $dbConnection))
{
    echo("Table '".$dbTable."' created<br />");
}
else
{
    echo("Error creating table '".$dbTable."': ".mysql_error()."<br />");
}

$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'users.csv' INTO ".$dbTable." FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (ID, Username, Password, UserType, FirstName, LastName, DOB, Phone, Department)";
if(mysql_query($sql, $dbConnection))
{
    echo("Added records to '".$dbTable."' table<br />");
}
else
{
    echo("Error inserting records into '".$dbTable."': ".mysql_error()."<br />");
}
```

Comment: You can import CSVs via PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: please specify exactly what that errors are.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. I hope it will work

```
    LOAD DATA INFILE '<filePath>' 
    INTO TABLE <tableName> 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
    (ID, Username, Password, UserType, FirstName, LastName, DOB, Phone, Department);
```

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific on the error, try to output

```
 mysql_error();
```

in your error handling and make sure the .csv file path is correct. Or go into mysql error log and issue:

```
 tailf /mysql.log or tail -f /mysql.log
```